# SwiftUI: @EnvironmentObject with ViewModifier?

Tags: swiftui, environmentobject, viewmodifier

Here is the idea of what I would like to do: my app's navigation contains a list, which displays a view on tap gesture which is triggered with a `ViewModifier` to perform an animation.

In a nutshell:

`MyList > MyViewModifier > MyView`

Since I want to pass some data from the list to the final view in this hierarchy, I was thinking of using `@StateObject`/`@EnvironmentObject` property wrappers. But I just realized I can't pass an `.environmentObject(xx)` to a ViewModifier like I would do with a View.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
struct TestModel: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    //@Published var whateverData I would like to fetch later and see appear in other views?
}

class TestObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var elements: [TestModel] = [
        TestModel(id: 1, name: "Element 1"),
        TestModel(id: 2, name: "Element 2"),
        TestModel(id: 3, name: "Element 3")
    ]
}

struct MyList: View {
    @StateObject var testObject = TestObject()
    @State var presenting = false
    @State var tappedId: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(testObject.elements) { element in
            Text(element.name)
                .onTapGesture {
                    tappedId = element.id
                    presenting = true
                }
        }
        .modifier(
            MyViewModifier(presented: $presenting, tappedId: tappedId)
            // .environmentObject(testObject) ?
        )
    }
}

struct MyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var presented: Bool
    var tappedId: Int?
    
    @EnvironmentObject var testObject: TestObject
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(
            ZStack {
                if presented {
                    MyView(testObject: _testObject, tappedId: tappedId)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var testObject: TestObject
    var tappedId: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            Text(testObject.elements.first(where: { $0.id == tappedId })?.name ?? "-")
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
    }
}
```

Of course this throws an error when trying to display TestView:

> No ObservableObject of type TestObject found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for TestObject may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

(FYI the reason why I want to use an environment object and pass it to the modifier and then the view is that I may want to call an API in `TestView` when it appears on screen, which would fetch more information of this object and dispatch this information both in `MyList` and `MyView`)

What are your recommendations here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not just passing `testObject` as a parameter to the modifier? Ex. `MyViewModifier(presented: $presenting, tappedId: tappedId, test: testObject)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was suggested in the comments, you could pass the object as a parameter to your `ViewModifier`.

Another option is to call `.environmentObject()` after `.modifier()` and you should be able to read that object from your modifier.

```swift
struct MyList: View {
    @StateObject var testObject = TestObject()
    @State var presenting = false
    @State var tappedId: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(testObject.elements) { element in
            // blah blah
        }
        .modifier(MyViewModifier(presented: $presenting, tappedId: tappedId))
        .environmentObject(testObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just got it to work this way. Thank you! I need to learn a little better how EnvironmentObjects are being passed from components to components now.